# How to schedule a task in Windows Task Scheduler with delay of 10 minutes after system restarted using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I want to schedule a task in Windows Task Scheduler which will run after system restarted with the delay of 10 minutes. I want to use PowerShell script to schedule the task.

Comment: Have you tried to script it? **Use PowerShell to Create Scheduled Tasks** <https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/>

Comment: Create a scheduled task, set trigger to startup and delay it with 10 minutes.

Comment: I already have one script to schedule a task using PowerShell. But now I want to run my task after every restart.

Answer (score 0):

By setting this trigger, the task is running after system restarts with the additional delay of 10 minutes.

```
$trigger=New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartUp 

trigger.Delay = 'PT10M'
trigger.Repetition = (New-ScheduTedTaskTrigger -once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionDuration (New-TimeSpan -Days 1000) -Repetitioninterval) (New-TimeSpan -Hours 2)). repetition
```